# How to get navController inside activity?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I use Jetpack Navigation for navigating between fragments and activity. So, I have a `MainActivity` with a `FragmentContainerView` in the layout. I can easily navigate from fragment to fragment/activity. But, I can't find a way how to navigate from one activity to another activity/fragment with `navController`.

For example, from fragment FA, I call `navController.navigate()` to activity A. Now, I want to navigate from activity A to activity B or fragment FB.

I already tried this:

```
val host = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = host.navController
```

But always got this error

```
null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A note from the navigation component guide

> Note: The Navigation component is designed for apps that have one main activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity is associated with a navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment that is responsible for swapping destinations as needed. In an app with multiple activity destinations, each activity has its own navigation graph.

You shouldn't use the navigation component to navigate from one activity to another. It is made to swap fragments on a Fragment container.

You can get `navController` inside `activity` using

```
val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

You also have to add `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` to your fragment container

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
/>
```

Comment: you can use <fragment> tag instead of <FragmentContainerView> and access navController in activity using Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragmentContainerView) where this refers to activity and R.id.fragmentContainerView is the id of <fragment> tag in activity xml file.

Answer (score 1):

For java coder;

it is possible to get NavController instance this way

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment =(NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                                     .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);

NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `FragmentContainerView` and `ViewBinding`, here is a cleaner way to do it:

YourActivity.kt

```kotlin
class YourActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var binding: YourActivityBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = YourActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navController = (binding.navHostFragment.getFragment<NavHostFragment>())
            .findNavController()
    }
}
```

your_activity.xml

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
/>
```